# Является ли тождественным сравнение?

Tags: javascript

Привет. Является ли сравнение 
`0 !== someElement.length`
и
`someElement.length !== 0` тождественным?

И почему существует два типа таких записей?

Comment: да, они будут равны, а запись, когда константа в условии ставится в начале, это для удобства, чтобы случайно не провтыкать и не присвоить в переменную эту самую константу

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно писать и так и так — разницы нет.

`0 !== someElement.length` называется [Условия Йоды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B).

Обычно это применяют в условиях равенства, а не неравества, т.е. например `0 == someElement.length`

А пишут так потому, что легко забыть дописать два раза `=` и в итоге в условии получалось вместо

```
if (someElement.length == 0) { ...
```

вот так

```
if (someElement.length = 0) { ...
```

В итоге, вместо сравнения получалось присваивание. Ошибки, конечно же, не выскакивало, ибо валидное выражение и программа отрабатывала, но не так как планировалось.

При условии

```
if (0 = someElement.length) { ...
```

возникнет ошибка (ибо нельзя константе что-то присвоить), которую сразу можно пофиксить. А остальное уже как единообразие стиля.

Comment: спасибо за более детальное обьяснение !